# lightslder onSliderLoad scroll to top not working

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to scroll to top everytime the slide is loaded. So that I can start from top to scroll the slide.

I tried this:

```
  onSliderLoad: function (el) {
               el.window.slider.scrollTo(0,0);

          }
```

but it didn't scroll the slider to its top when the new slide is loaded.

How can I make the slider to go to top ?